# How do I get separate values from a single cell with multiple values in it separated by commas using xlrd in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd

So let's say I have a column in excel called names and then in the first cell it has "George, Bill, Sally". How using xlrd would I separate those values and print them in Python.

```
csv_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))) + 
"\FilePath\\"
file_location = csv_dir + "filename"
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    name = sheet.cell_value(row, 0)
    print(name)
```

So right now I get George, Bill, Sally as the result. I want it to print out as:

```
George 
Bill
Sally
```

With each name printing one line at a time. Basically I want to print out three different strings each representing one name instead of one string for all three names.

Comment: "Text to Columns" works well in excel.

Comment: @SolarMike I would do that, but I'm trying to do this without altering the excel file at all.

Comment: You tagged excel so...

Comment: I tagged excel since I'm importing from an excel file.

Comment: Haven't used `xlrd` before but you could use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) in your loop to transform the comma separated names.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to print it out, use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

```py
for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    name = sheet.cell_value(row, 0)
    print(name.replace(',', '\n').replace(' ', ''))
```

if you want to actually put the values in a list, use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```py
for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    name = sheet.cell_value(row, 0)
    as_list = name.replace(' ', '').split(',')  # the replace is to remove any spaces
    print(*as_list, sep='\n')
```